# Trying to profile CodeIgniter Application but can't get report

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have tried to include `$this->output->enable_profiler(true);` in my controller as per the official documentation. I've added the line of code under `parent::__construct();` in my constructor, but the webpage doesn't load.

UPDATED

This is withing my constructor:

```
parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
        $sections = array(
            'config' => FALSE,
            'queries' => TRUE,
            'post' => FALSE,
            'memory_usage' => TRUE,
            'get' => FALSE,
            'benchmarks' => TRUE,
            'controller_info' => FALSE,
            'url_string' => FALSE,
        );
        $this->output->set_profiler_sections($sections);
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't load"? The entire page doesn't? The profiler script doesn't? Is there an error? Please provide the relevant segment of your code.

Comment: Yes the entire page doesn't load, there is no error.

Comment: Does it load normally? Without the enable profiler?

Comment: Yes it loads normally without the profiler, also when i enable the profiler it doesn't load any other page even if it has a different controller

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a copy/paste error but you have

```
$this-output-set_profiler_sections($sections);
```

When you should have:

```
$this->output->set_profiler_sections($sections);
```

Comment: Sorry yeah, that was a mistake when I configured the profile but I firstly started with `$this->output->enable_profiler(true);` which gave me the loading problem initially. But thanks for noticing, I still have the problem though :(

Comment: Have you tried setting the profiler inside your controller method rather than the constructor. I have a suspicion it does not work in the constructor.